# Abs function for complicated complex arguments

Tags: complex

[image]

I want to find the Abs square of this complex expression.

I tried using Abs command and then squaring it but nothing happened, it just showed 'Abs'  in the output. I also tried multiplying it with its conjugate but to no avail.

I think the problem is that it doesn't know which terms are complex and which are real. Here everything is real except the Iota part of course.

I do not know how to specify others as real or find its Absolute value in general. May anyone suggest something?

Comment: MA assumes that all your variables are complex. Use `ComplexExpand[Abs[...]]`

Comment: Thanks that worked